# asp.net EF core MVC cant access data from third foreign key table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Hello playing around with asp.net core MVC but got stuck and need some help.
I'm trying to get my index for courses to show the last name of the instructor but can't figure out how to access the information in the third table. I manage to get the InstructerID from the Departmenttable

```
    public class CourseIndexData
    {
        public IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
    }
```

```
      public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {

            var viewModel = new CourseIndexData();
            viewModel.Courses = await _context.Courses
                  .Include(i => i.Department)
                    .ThenInclude(i => i.Instructor)
                  .ToListAsync();

            return View(viewModel);

        }
```

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.SchoolViewModels.CourseIndexData

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
<h1>Index</h1>
<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Instructor
            </th>
            <th>
                Department
            </th>
            <th>
                Title
            </th>
            <th>
                Credits
            </th>

            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.Courses) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                ????????
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Credits)
            </td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a graph of data, so it would be:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.Instructor.LastName)
```

You do not really need to have Departments and Instructors properties on your ViewModel (CourseIndexData) because all of that data is effectively inside of Courses and linked via the navigation properties.

Comment: We've all been there. ;)